# Am I using GetComponents and IgnoreCollision correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm trying to get a player character in a 2D sidescroller to ignore collisions with specific objects in an array when it does a dash action. But my first attempt isn't working. No errors, it just doesn't work. The character still collides with the specific objects while dashing.

```
 private Collider2D col;
 public Collider2D[] dashMasks;

 void Awake()
 {
     col = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
     dashMasks = GetComponents<Collider2D>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if(dashing)
     {
         foreach(Collider2D mask in dashMasks)
         {
             Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(col, mask);
         }
     }
}
```

Did I do the `GetComponenets` call incorrectly or did I do the `IgnoreCollision` incorrectly, or maybe both?

Comment: Where is `dashing` set and what is happening in `Update()` when it's true? It appears all the colliders are on the same gameObject.

Comment: Dashing is part of the player controller accessed from another script. I left that full function out for the sake of brevity. When dashing is true it means the player is in the dashing state, which all works. I originally had the player ignoring collisions while dashing simply by disabling its collider while dashing but this can cause the player to fall off the stage so I need to set it to ignore collisions with only specific objects,

Comment: OK. Is `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` getting called? Add `Physics2D.GetIgnoreCollision()` under that call and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I tested your situation and it's working now.
Unity version is 5.1.2f Personal.
[Screenshot of the editor. Cube has 'PlayerController', Rigidbody2D, and BoxCollider2D.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX0fd.png)

Here is the code. If you press Space bar, you can pass Block sprite. If not press, of course you can't pass.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

float speed = 5;
bool dashing = false;
BoxCollider2D coll;
BoxCollider2D blockColl;

void Awake() {
    coll = this.transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
    blockColl = GameObject.Find ("Block").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
}

void Update()
{
    dashing = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space);
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (coll, blockColl, dashing);
}

void FixedUpdate () 
{
    float dirX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float dirY = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector2 (dirX, dirY);

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = movement * speed;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you already set dashMasks in the editor.
So you shouldn't set dashMasks in this script again.

```
private Collider2D col;
public Collider2D[] dashMasks;

void Awake()
{
    col = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    //dashMasks = GetComponents<Collider2D>(); // delete it.
}

void Update()
{
    if(dashing)
    {
        foreach(Collider2D mask in dashMasks)
        {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(col, mask);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything. The proper colliders do show up in the inspector when I assign game objects to the array

Comment: I posted another answer. You can check about it.